# 3DESKey and LTPA password from IBM Bluemix cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, ltpa

How to get **3DESKey** and **LTPA password** from IBM Bluemix cloud? I need it to decode user info from **LtpaToken2** cookies.
In Websphere I can get it from application server key file. There is `com.ibm.websphere.ltpa.3DESKey` property. Is there any similar property on the IBM Bluemix cloud?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Bluemix is a Platform as a Service. Encryption keys are specific to servers or individual applications. LPTA is an authentication technology specific to WebSphere and Lotus servers. You would need to instantiate a WebSphere server runtime on Bluemix, then get your authentication key from the server.

Comment: It is a Java application that runs on Liberty server. It returns LtpaToken2 in cookies. But in this configuration I can not find 3DESKey that I need to decode user info from the LTPA token.